# Show two texts in dart at different positions

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new at flutter. I coded an example from youtube. At the home screen I have a text at the top:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
      child: Text(
        gameHasStarted ? '' : 'My App',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to show another text at the bottom. Or on a another position. How to do that? I tried it with `Row` and `Column` but, then the two texts are depended from each other.

Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOU3A.png)

Comment: Add image for example what you want to design

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap this part with Stack and set your Text where you want

```
Stack(
          children: const [
            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              left: 50,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 50,
              right: 110,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

or also use with align in stack

```
Stack(
          children: const [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text("Hello3"),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Text("Hello4"),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Welcome any time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after wrapping both text with column ,
give `mainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` .

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Only if you could provide a preview of screen, I could provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be using the column and setting its properties

```
Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children:[
    Text('My App'),
    Text('My Text'),
  ],
),
```